# Yii2 dblib connection charset

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, yii2-advanced-app

I can connect to the database but charset is wrong. It is microsoft server database (mssql).

```
<?php return array (
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'dblib:host=*******;port=1433;dbname=*******;charset=utf8',
  'username' => '**********',
  'password' => '**********',
  'charset'  => 'utf8',
); ?>
```

If I use mb_convert_encoding like this then I get right characters but how can I make my connection right?

```
print_r(mb_convert_encoding($dbString, 'utf-8', "iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Please mention error message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all on the server check whether the installed drivers **php_mssql** and **php_pdo_mssql** or not.

Check the output of phpinfo() to be sure...

```
 'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'dblib:host=localhost;dbname=test123',
        'emulatePrepare' => false, // comment this if it cause any issue 
        'username' => 'XXXX',
        'password' => 'XXXXX',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
                ),
```

or Else

May be problem is with the sql server itself, if you uses sqlserver 2000 in which  sqlsrv driver may not be compatible check that. if not migrate to sqlserver 2008 or any compitable version might be work smoothly.